# Postgres concat schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema, concatenation

One of my PostgreSQL databases contains different schemas that share the same structure.

```
-- schema region_a
CREATE TABLE region_a.auth_user (
username NOT NULL,
password not null,
last_name NOT NULL,
Company varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE region_a.user_email (
useer_id NOT NULL,
email varchar(255)

);

-- schema region_b
CREATE TABLE region_b.auth_user (
username NOT NULL,
password not null,
last_name NOT NULL,
Company varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE region_b.user_email (
useer_id NOT NULL,
email varchar(255)

);

-- schema region_c
-- ...
```

I have a superuser table which contains all users from all tenant in this case schema

```
CREATE TABLE public.superusers (
username NOT NULL,
password not null,
last_name NOT NULL,
schema_nane NOT NULL,
Company varchar(255)
);
```

Now I am wondering how to create a trigger when I remove a user from superuser table inserted in the corresponding schema

Comment: Hi Edward, please do not suggest edits to answers on your questions with clarifications. Instead, [edit] your own question with the clarification. Edits on answers that clearly conflict with the author's original intent are not appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate (drop) the tables from each region and recreate then as a view (or a Materialized View).

```
create table public.all_users (
       id          integer generated always as identity
     , user_name   text not null
     , last_name   text not null
     , region      text not null
     , email       varchar(255)     
     , company     varchar(255)
     , constraint  all_users_pk
                   primary key (id) 
    );

create table public.all_users_password( 
       id          integer  
     , password    text      -- should be encrypted 
     , constraint  all_users_pw_pk
                   primary key (id) 
     , constraint  all_users_pw_fk 
                   foreign key (id)
                   references public.all_users(id)
     ) ;

create or replace view region_a.users as 
   select id          
        , user_name   
        , last_name        
        , email          
        , company
     from public.all_users
    where region = 'region_a' ; 

create or replace view region_b.users as 
   select id          
        , user_name   
        , last_name        
        , email          
        , company
     from public.all_users
    where region = 'region_b' ; 

--- same then for region_c, region_d, ...
```

Note: I removed split passwords into into their individual table and did *intentionally* did not include them in the region user tables; doing so is always a security breach. But, include then if you wish. Also renames column Schema_name to region i.e what it id not where it's stored. Again just a strong recommendation.

Comment: If you use views no trigger is needed, all maintenance is in the public table. Any change is picked up automatically when the view is queried again. Keep in mind that a view is just a stored query.

Comment: See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gDwdRL5EBFP2fa84oqCHsy/0). It shows not only a delete, but also an update and an insert.

Comment: Also I suggest you look at Postgres Documentation for Views starting [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html).